# Authentication error when callling SMS sending API in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am getting below error when I execute this code to call this REST API for sending SMS. What is the issue?

> {"status":{"code":"1010","type":"error","description":"Authentication error."}}

Below is my code

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @reqHead AS VARCHAR(8000) =  
 '{
   "x-authorization":"N2I2OWU2OTg0MmE0M2JkMmNhYmQyZjg1MDJjYWY1",
   "Email":"testing@gmail.com",
    "content-type":"application/json"
}'

DECLARE @Body AS VARCHAR(8000) = 
'{
  "data": [
    {
      "message_bag": {
        "numbers": "0700000000",
        "message": "testing sms.",
        "sender": "MY_SENDER_ID"
      }
    }
  ]
}'  ;
-- Code Snippet  MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp     MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post','https://mysmsprovider.co.ke/api/messaging', 'false'
--select @reqHead
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', @reqHead, 'Content-Type', 'application/json' 
 --select @body
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: How many headers can you set at once in a single setRequestHeader call?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out by passing the headers one by one instead of passing the header object

removed this line
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', @reqHead, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

added this

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'X-Authorization', 'N2I2OWU2OTg0MmE0M2JkMmNhYmQyZjg1MDuuuuJjYWY1'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'email','myemail@gmail.com'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null,'Content-Type', 'application/json'